# CMD - how does one set a variable using other variables in the variable name

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, set

I want to set a variable that uses another variable in its name. I want to do something like:

```
set a=2
set b=0
set s%a%%b%=Yee
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, but I want to be able to call the variable by doing:

```
echo %s20%
```

So it would echo `Yee`. This may be something you can't do, but it would make setting lots of variables much easier.

Comment: The concept you use is called _array_. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
set a=2
set b=0
set s%a%%b%=Yee


call echo %%s%a%%b%%%
:: OR ::
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

echo !s%a%%b%!

endlocal
```

Better use the way with the delayed expansion as the call hits the performance.